# How to trigger onChange trigger on inserts only

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that sends emails when lines are appended or inserted to a sheet. The problem I have is that the python script that is connected to the google sheet purges sheet "new_strikes" then inserts new information in the same Google sheet. I have a **onChange** trigger like so:

```
function trigFunc(e){
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(activeSheet.getName() != 'new_strikes') return;
  Utilities.sleep(30);
  sendEmail();
}
```

The problem is when I purge then insert data into this sheet, the script runs twice--once for the purge and once for the edit. Since the trigger sends an email, I get two emails. How do I modify the code or trigger so that it only tracks the insertion of data and therefore sends one email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling  `trigFunc(e)` directly from the on change trigger, add the following function to your project and set your trigger to call it:

```
function respondToOnChange(e){
  if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') trigFunc(e);
}
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events